# Can JavaScript interact with CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

If  I set something in linked JavaScript to be a variable:

```js
color1 = green;
```

Can I then later call the variable in CSS, like so?

```
div {
  color : color1
}
```

Comment: Until CSS actually properly [**supports variables**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables)...no.

Comment: The closest you're going to get to what you're asking at the moment (regarding variables) is to use a CSS pre-processing language such as SASS or LESS: [http://sass-lang.com/](http://sass-lang.com/)

Comment: You need to learn JavaScript and CSS before you try to combine the two. Also, your question is incomprehensible, please rephrase.

Answer (score 3):

No, not this way. However if you are interested in using varibales in CSS, you may want to learn [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), [SASS](http://sass-lang.com) or another CSS preprocessor.

Comment: Why not also mention SASS? You are recommending a specific tool. This is biased. Try to offer ***all CSS preprocessors*** to give OP research options.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, yeah, go ahead, list all of them :). Hopefully you do not think LESS and SASS are the only ones (even though they are the most popular).

Comment: No, I know there are others, but they are indeed the most popular.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, true, ok, I have updated my answer. Thx for comment.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
<h1 style="color:red;" id="red"> I am red </h1>
<script> //JS

document.getElementById("red").setAttribute("style", "color:green;");
</style>
```

In the above example, JS code selects the element `h1` using id and changes it's color to green. So JS is actually altering the inline CSS attribute.

Answer (score 0):

No. CSS can not access Javascript variables.

To use your variable in this way you would assign it to your elements `style` property using Javascript. It may look something like this for a single element:

```js
var color1 = 'green',
    el = document.getElementById('myDiv')

el.style.color = color1;
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">Hello</div>
```

Or this for a number of elements:

```js
var color1 = 'green',
    els = document.querySelectorAll('.changeColour')

for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].style.color = color1;
}
```

```html
<div class="changeColour">Hello</div>
<div class="changeColour">Hello</div>
```